# What is the alternative to using selectors with props in ngrx

Tags: ngrx

I am reading about `selectors` on the [ngrx website](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-with-props) and I stumbled upon `selectors` with `props`.

The ngrx team said it is deprecated but they didn't provide alternative to it. I want to use `selectors` with `props` in my application.

Is there any other alternative to using selectors with props?

If there is, how do I do it?.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980

Comment: The recommended way is to use factory selectors `sel1 = (id: number) => createSelector(...)`. Have a look at v12 migration: https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v12

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The word "deprecated" in the notice is actually a link, though a hard one to notice due to the color of the banner it's in. It links to [a GitHub Issue discussing selectors with props](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980).

That issue raises the concern that, with Angular 12+ being in [strict mode](https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode) by default, developers are likely to run into a shortcoming in the implementation of selectors with props - namely that the prop values are not strongly typed or may be incorrectly typed.

The suggested approach is to use a factory selector. Essentially, instead of passing props as parameters of the selector, you take the props as arguments to a function defined by the selector.

So instead of:

```js
export const getCount = createSelector(
  getCounterValue,
  (counter, props) => counter * props.multiply
);

const count = this.store.select(getCount, 5);
```

You would use:

```js
export const getCount = (multiply: number) => createSelector(
  getCounterValue,
  (counter) => counter * multiply
);

const count = this.store.select(getCount(5));
```

[Gunnar B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4251829/gunnar-b)'s comment helpfully links to a migration guide with [a section about moving from selectors with props to factory selectors](https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v12#selectors-with-props) if you need more information.